# How to check email format in string using javascript and php?

Tags: javascript, php, email

How to check email format in string using javascript and php ?

When test php and javascript code. It's will show result `No email in this string` how can i apply php and javascript to check email format in string ?

This is PHP

```
<?php
$strEmail = "email: mail@example.com";
if (!eregi("^[_a-z0-9-]+(\.[_a-z0-9-]+)*@[a-z0-9-]+(\.[a-z0-9-]+)*(\.[a-z]{2,3})$", $strEmail)) { 
    echo "No email in this string";
} else {
    echo "Have email in this string";
}
?>
```

And this is Javascript

```
<script>
    var value_check_email = "email: mail@example.com";
    var email_format_fn = /^(([^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+)*)|(\".+\"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;
    include_email = email_format_fn.test(value_check_email);
    if(include_email === true)
    {
        alert("Have email in this string");
    }
    else
    {
        alert("No email in this string");
    }
</script>
```

Comment: what is the prefix `email:`? are you sure you don't want `mailTo:`?

Comment: No `email: mail@example.com` is string value for example input value.

Comment: No `email: mail@example.com` is string value for example input value or textarea value from user.